# Heroku/Sidekiq not finding Database Record after_commit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, sidekiq

Here is my code:

`after_commit :notify, on: :create`

The `notify` method, calls to `ServiceRequestMailerWorker.perform_async(self.id, email)` and here is my that mailer looks like:

```
class ServiceRequestMailerWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker

  def perform(service_request_id, send_to)
    @service_request = ServiceRequest.find(service_request_id)
    @customer = @service_request.customer
    WarrantyMailer.submitted(@service_request, @customer, send_to).deliver
  end
end
```

Error:

```
2014-07-22T03:05:25.626004+00:00 app[worker.1]: 2014-07-22T03:05:25.625Z 2 TID-os0kqm6sg DEBUG: enqueued retry: {"retry":true,"queue":"default","class":"ServiceRequestMailerWorker","args":[787,"email@email.com"],"jid":"f1d8f416718bafa8c809fa3e","enqueued_at":1405998308.4219391,"error_message":"Couldn't find ServiceRequest with 'id'=787 [WHERE (company_id IS NOT NULL)]","error_class":"ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound","failed_at":1405998308.618538,"retry_count":0}
```

This ONLY happens in my staging environment on Heroku. I have been trying to debug this for hours. Anyone else run into this issue?

Comment: Do you have a `service_request` record with id `787` in staging environment?

Comment: Yep, I can log into the rails console and type `ServiceRequest.find(787)` and a record is found

Comment: does it eventually find the record and complete the work?

Comment: also what database are you using? I'm guessing Postgres

Comment: @dennismonsewicz Did you solve this? I'm having the exact same issue and it's driving me crazy

Comment: Looks like it happens with default queue. Setting up custom queue solved issue for me.